# How can i decode the string encoded in c# using utf8

Tags: c#, decoder

I encode  string in c# using this code

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] asciiBytes =encoding.GetBytes(result);
```

but I cant decode asciibytes to string can any one help me??

Comment: You would just reverse it: `string text = encoding.GetString(asciiBytes)`. Note that `asciiBytes` is very badly named, however - UTF-8 != ASCII. Also, I'd typically use `Encoding.UTF8` rather than creating a new `UTF8Encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

`encoding.GetString(asciiBytes)`
In some .NET versions this extension methode is not available so you have to use:
`encoding.GetString(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)`

Another note: ASCII and UTF-8 are not the same. So the wording asciiBytes is a bit confusing.

You can also use the static instance instead of creating an `encoding`object.

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(..)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` isn't an extension method - it's just a normal method which has been available since .NET 1.0. It's not available in the PCL/Silverlight/Windows Phone, but that's slightly different.